# Composer Installation Error on Windows 10: The installation directory is not writable

Tags: windows, composer-php

I try to install Composer (downloaded from https://getcomposer.org/download/) on Windows 10, but I get the following error message: The installation directory "C:\Users\BAB2~1\AppData\Local\Temp\is-5EP2P.tmp" is not writable.
[Composer Installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ccrt.png)
I have given full access to this directory, but it doesn't help. Could you please suggest any ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. download https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
2. drop `composer.phar` file into your PHP folder
3. make sure this PHP folder is on-path (so that you can call `php` everywhere)

   - if not, add the PHP folder to your environment `PATH` variable
4. run `php composer.phar` for testing. you should get Composer's help output
5. create a little batch file `composer.bat` to invoke composer easier:

   C:\PHP> `echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat`

This enables you to run `composer` in any PHP project folder.

Comment: I just succeeded in installing Composer.  Thank you very much for helpful answer.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: The echo command did not work for me using windows powershell. [This blog post] (http://leedavis81.github.io/global-installation-of-composer-on-windows/) tells you how to do it in Powershell.